# using libchromiumcontent to render user interfaces

Tags: chromium-embedded

I would like to be able to render user interfaces for cross-platform audio plug-ins (VST, audiounit) on desktop machines using HTML UI, in a similar approach to this project https://github.com/russellmcc/audiounitjs

Unfortunately native web views are significantly different [and particularly limited on windows].

I'm investigating whether I can use libchromiumcontent from the electron project to do this, but I can't find a basic tutorial that looks appropriate e.g. a basic c++ app rendering a UI using HTML. I'm not even sure if that's gonna be possible. Perhaps I have to wait for mozilla's servo? because I am developing audio plug-ins, the plug-in host controls the main application loop. Does this means I cannot use libchromiumcontent?

thanks

Comment: Why not just use the electron project?